# LyX won't detect TeXLive

Tags: lyx, texlive, ubuntu, linux

I just upgraded my TeX installation on Ubuntu to the latest TeXLive (2021). I previously was using the `texlive` package from the repository.

- I uninstalled the previous installation
- I ran the TeXLive installer `install-tl.sh`
- I updated by system path to include `/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux` and can run `pdflatex` from the terminal

```bash
~/Documents$ which latex
/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/latex
```

- I started LyX, lauched `Reconfigure`, then restarted LyX

But when I open my last document:

[image: Document class not available]

And recanning TeX information does not help either:

[image: TeX information]

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I also needed to add the TeXLive path to Preferences > Paths > PATH prefix. I (incorrectly) assumed that LyX would rely on the system path.

Additionally, it turns out from discussion with other contributors that I was mistaken in adding the path to the `.bashrc` file, but should have added it to the `.profile` file.

Note that it worked before only because I was using the `texlive` package from the Ubuntu repository, where the executables are stored in the `/usr/bin` directory.

Comment: Where **exactly** did you add your path change on your system (not in LyX), if you do this in the wrong way editors started from a menu or via double click will ever see the path change

Comment: I added `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux` to `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: As I expected. That is your main problem. If the editor is started say, via a Menu, then anything in `bashrc` is NEVER seen! Additionally, what you are doing there is wrong, if you have two LaTeX installations then you're still using the old one. Add `export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH` to `.profile` as well (create it it it does not exist already). Then log out and in again. `.profile` is only read at login, and the env variables it sets is seen by ALL subsequent processes including those started by a menu.

Comment: This issue of only adding the PATH change to `.bashrc` is sadly a very very common mistake.

Comment: +1 what to everything daleif wrote. I suggest that daleif write an answer. I suppose there's still a puzzle left: why did things work well for 2020? Did you set PATH in a different way?

Comment: Oooookaaaay! I'm not an expert on Linux and all documentation I had read was only about the `.bashrc` file. The reason it worked before is that I was then using the distribution from the Ubuntu repository, where the executables are stored in the usual `/user/bin` folder. Thanks for answering my question _and_ making me learn something!

Comment: @mrgou ah, that explains the puzzle! Thanks for getting back to us. Perhaps it's worth an edit to your answer so that users don't think that LyX is ignoring the system PATH.

Comment: @scottkosty, good idea, done!